# How to prove $\int_{\Omega} \sum_{i=1}^{N} f_i(x)dx$ is equivilant with $\sum_{i=1}^{N} \int_{\Omega} f_i(x)u_i(x)dx$

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, image-segmentation

I have a 2D image defined on a region $\Omega$. Assume that the region can be separated into $N$ sub-regions $\Omega_i$ such that $$\forall i,j=1... N:\Omega_i \cap\Omega_j=\emptyset$$ and $$\bigcup_{n=1}^{N}\Omega_n =\Omega$$

Let $u_i(x)=1$ if $x \in \Omega_i$, otherwise $u_i(x)=0$. Then for a familiy $\{f_n:n\in 1..N\}$ of functions on $\Omega$ we have $$x \in \Omega_k \implies \sum_{i=1}^{N}f_i(x)u_i(x)=f_k(x)$$

I have a energy function that is defined as following
$$E_1=\int_{\Omega} \sum_{i=1}^{N} f_i(x)dx$$

Does the below equation $E_2$ equate with above energy function $E_1$? How to prove it?
$$E_2=\sum_{i=1}^{N} \int_{\Omega}  f_i(x)u_i(x)dx$$

That is my prove
[image]

Comment: Don't you mean $\sum_{i=1}^N f(x) u_i(x) = f_i(x)$?

Comment: Your prerequisites are not quite right. $\Omega_i \cup \Omega_j = \Omega$ for $i,j=1\dots N$ doesn't make a lot of sense if $N>2$. What you mean is that the full space is covered by all $\Omega$, and not by any pair. So you should write $\bigcup_{i=1}^N \Omega_i = \Omega$. 
Next, there is very little to prove if $N$ is finite. In that case you just use the additivity of the integral's domain and the linearity of the integral to transform one into the other.

Comment: @Jazzmaniac: Yes. That is right. However, Just assume N=3 is more common case in brain segmentation. What do you think about $E_1(x)$ and $E_2(x)$?

Comment: @geometrikal: $\sum_{i=1}{^N}f(x)u_i(x)=f_i(x)$ for $x \in \Omega_i$ because $ u_i(x)=1$ for $x \in \Omega_i$, and $u_i(x)=0$ for otherwise. Hence, $\sum_{i=1}{^N}f(x)u_i(x)=f_1(x)u_1(x)+...f_i(x)u_i(x)+f_N(x) u_N(x)= f_i(x) u_i(x)=f_i(x)$

Comment: What you just wrote for @geometrikal is not accurate. He's totally right saying that $\sum_{i=1}^N f_i(x)u_i(x)$ cannot result in $f_i(x)$, because all information about the index $i$ is eliminated by the sum on the lhs. Also regarding your last reply to me, I already said that there's not much to prove for finite $N$, meaning that the identity is "nearly obvious". If you explain what you have trouble with I will help you. But currently it looks like you just need to brush up your math notation and integral properties.

Comment: Thank Jazzamaniac for your comment. Actually, I am following a paper that show above equation. However, it did not prove the equation. I updated my demonstrationist and the image to clearly show what I am doing. For each pixel $x$, I define a energy $E(x)$ that is sum of each $f_i(x)$ ($f_i$ is characterize function of each region). So, total energy for whole image will be integration of $x$ in $\Omega$ domain. After that, I seperated the $\Omega$ into sub-domain. It look likes computation $E(x)$ in each sub-region ($x$ will only run in each region), and then compute the sum. Is it correct?

Comment: The paper references are http://www.math.gsu.edu/~xye/papers/ZYC13_Seg_TIP.pdf  (Eq. 21) and http://kaihuazhang.net/J_papers/tcyb2014a.pdf  (Eq 17)

Comment: I have edited your question to remove all issues and clear it up

Comment: I'm sorry for being frank, but the "proof" you posted is full of notational, conceptual and mathematical errors. I believe you should invest some time and possibly money in improving your math skills if you plan of pursuing this kind of work. Or maybe you just need to work more carefully and focused.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Starting from your $E_2$ and exchanging the finite sum with the integral we get this:

$$E_2=\sum_{i=1}^N \int_\Omega f_i(x) u_i(x) dx = \int_\Omega \sum_{i=1}^N f_i(x) u_i(x) dx$$

Next we can use the disjoint cover $\{\Omega_i\}$ of $\Omega$ to split up the integral:

$$E_2 = \sum_{k=1}^N \int_{\Omega_k} \sum_{i=1}^N f_i(x) u_i(x) dx$$

The $x$ in the integral are now from $\Omega_k$ and we can apply your identity for the sum over $f_i(x) u_i(x)$:

$$E_2 = \sum_{k=1}^N \int_{\Omega_k} f_k(x) dx$$

This is almost your $E_1$, but not quite. We cannot exchange the integral with the sum because the integral depends on the summation index. Extending the integration region to $\Omega$ is also not possible without reintroducing a selection function. So your $E_1$ and $E_2$ are not equal. The closest thing to $E_1$ is what I have derived above.

Comment: I just ask you a small question: Do you look at two my references papers? From your comment, it shown that both of them are wrong, Right?

Comment: @user8430, I have not really looked much into the papers you linked and so I cannot comment regarding their correctness. I can only say that the version you asked for is not correct.